# applyBindings() on <select> is causing my subscribe() to fire,

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a select:

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="value: title.value, foreach: title.choices">
  <option data-bind="text: name, value: code"></option>
</select>
```

With Js:

```
self.title.choices = [
        { "code": "", "name": "" },
        { "code": "MR", "name": "Mr" },
        { "code": "MRS", "name": "Mrs" }
      ]
self.title.value = ko.observable('').extend({
  required: true
});

self.title.value.subscribe(function (newValue) {
  self.gender.value('male');
});
```

I then call applyBindings, and the select list iterates over the options, and fire's my subscribe function 3 times (1x for each option). It annoyingly then updates my other observable, how can I prevent this happening?

Comment: Can you post the code where you add the 3 options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `options` binding instead.

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="value: title.value,
                                        options: title.choices,
                                        optionsText: 'code',
                                        optionsValue: 'name',
                                        optionsCaption: ''">
</select>
```

```
self.title.choices = [
    { "code": "MR", "name": "Mr" },
    { "code": "MRS", "name": "Mrs" }
];
self.title.value = ko.observable('').extend({
    required: true
});
```